# How to create SNMPv1 community string?

Tags: snmp

I'm currently working on SNMPv1 and I'm wondering how to define a community string generally on my server.

Using snmpset and snmpget, I have to specify a community name, but I can only use community names that are registered somewhere, like `public` or `private`. How can I add one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of SNMP agent/server do you use? On Windows or Linux? Without such information this is not even a question itself.

Comment: @LexLi I'm running a UNIX server and I'm using the commands like `snmpget` and such. As I guessed, this is not dependable of any software, I thought this was a standard that every device has... I'm confused.

Comment: For a server, check [`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html). For a client, use the [`-c` flag](http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpgetnext) with `snmpget` or `snmpgetnext`.

Comment: I already figured out how to use the `-c` option on `snmpget` and `snmpset`, but I can't think how I can create those community names (as I can't just set a new one when using `snmpset`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most detailed guide on how to configure SNMP agents on common UNIX or Linux system is from *Essential SNMP* book,

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/ch07_03.htm

Under *7.3.4. Net-SNMP (Formerly UCD-SNMP)* you can find the steps and it applies to all systems that uses Net-SNMP. That's why @PP. asks you to check `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`, which is the Net-SNMP configuration file.

My personal suggestion is that you directly go to *7.3.4.2. Creating a configuration by hand* and create the config file by hand. Then you can easily set `rwcommunity` and `rocommunity`. That's the community names you would like to set.

If you do have time later on, make sure you go through this small book, as it does include most of the details about SNMP you should be aware of.

Comment: Does that contain informations on how to create new OIDs? To that question, I'm still stuck (how can I create a new entry, for example, 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.10)?

Comment: @FlorianMüller, that's in chapter 11, http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/ch11_01.htm