# How to add a new OID and fill values?

Tags: snmp, mib

I need a good beginner advice - all tutorial I searched are either outdated or do not contain the information how to achieve what I want.

I want:

- Create a new OID (now under experimental, later we will reserve a new OID as enterprise)
- Under this OID, I'd like to create a table (sequence) with two string columns.
- Somehow, this definition has to be compiled and added to the existing MIB on our server. But how?

That's actually all I want, but I didn't make it to find out all this.

**PLEASE** if you could just point out simple steps, that would be quite great!

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling someone how to write a MIB is extremely difficult.  It's a complex process  and you need to understand a lot of the background behind MIB design.  I strongly recommend you go read a book ([Understanding SNMP MIBs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134377087) being one of the best).  Without learning about MIBs properly first, you'll make too many mistakes.

As for software, it's nearly impossible to answer without you explaining your environment:  what operating system, machine type, etc.  If you're using Net-SNMP, see the [Coding Tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Coding_Tutorials) page.  If you're using a commercial product (eg, SNMP research), then go ask them for help!

Comment: I actually didn't see the tutorial section on this Wiki page, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you read carefully what I posted to your previous question?

[How to create SNMPv1 community string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182570/how-to-create-snmpv1-community-string/18200053#comment26679254_18200053)

If you do spare some time to go through the classic book your ABC questions can be easily answered by that book.

If something on that book is out of date, simply post smaller questions on those specific points and you will get corresponding assistance.

Don't post some big and vague question especially when some proper Googling does show good links. For example search for "net-snmp extend".

Comment: I've printed out the whole book, but this one seems to use `MACRO SYNTAX` as mentioned [->here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255794/asn-1-compiler-error-token-syntax-unexpected). I should actually have this work today so I do not have enough time to read a complete book with very much theoretical and not very much (or outdated) practical stuff.

I actually googled the whole week and I didn't manage the simple way to extend the own MIB, maybe because I don't even understand C (and the whole MIB compiling process)

Comment: When you don't even understand C or any other similar programming language, it is almost impossible to extend  an SNMP agent and no wonder when good search results appear you find them less helpful. You'd better hire someone to assist.

Comment: With the Net-SNMP agent you can use perl or shell scripts to extend the agent, but it's much less efficient than C.